# Django: return render not looking for urls.py in sub application

Tags: python, django

I have a `urls.py` file in `mysite`, which points to everything in the `shark/` folder to the `shark/urls.py` file:

*mysite/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include ('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
    url(r'^shark/', include('shark.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),
```

In the `shark/` folder, I have the following view file, with a function that loads `target.html`. However it cannot find this file, because it looks in the `mysite/urls.py` file instead the one in the `shark/` folder:

```
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(target)

def target(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        answers=[]
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'target.html', {'form':form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'target.html', {'form': form})
```

And as a result I get this error message:

```
^admin/
^polls/
^accounts/
^shark/
^ ^$ [name='index']
^ ^admin/
The current URL, target/, didn't match any of these.
```

Even though the URL would be listed, but in the `shark/urls.py` file.

*shark/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^get_name', views.get_name, name='get_name'),
    url(r'^target', views.target, name='target'),
```

How can I correct this problem, so that render requests in the `shark/` subfolder will reference the `urls.py` file in that particular folder and not the main `urls.py` in the `mysite/` folder?

Comment: Add it to urlpatterns in mysite/urls.py and not in your app - this will fix the problem.

Comment: Thats because its `shark/target`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a match if the url were: `shark/target` since you specified the `shark` prefix in the root `urls.py`. Use an empty string there and it will match `target/`. e.g.:

**mysite\urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include ('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
    url(r'', include('shark.urls')),  # Now shark urls will match without the prefix
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),
```

It's generally a good practice to keep app urls separate and include from a root urls module.

Comment: 'empty string there'. Where?

Comment: Currently I'm addressing the target with return HttpResponseRedirect(target). How can I make it shark/target?

Comment: You can do `return HttpResponseRedirect('/shark/target')`

Comment: But it still doesn't look in shark.urls if I put url(r'shark/', include('shark.urls')), How can i fix this without having it an empty string?

Comment: So to double check, when using `url(r'^shark/', include('shark.urls'))` in root urls and `url(r'^target', views.target, name='target')` in shark urls, after navigating using your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/shark/target` what do you get? Does `def target` handle `request.method == 'GET'` in some way?

Answer (score 0):

The `shark/urls.py` is only loaded for paths that begin with `shark/`, because that's what you are specifying in your `mysite/urls.py`. Therefore, to additionally load the path `target/` from your "sharks" app, you have to specifically mention it in the main `mysite/urls.py`.

*mysite/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^shark/', include('shark.urls')),
    url(r'^target/', shark.views.target)),
    ...
```

Comment: But the target function is called from the views in the shark folder. So shouldn't it know that I'm referring to the shark folder? How can I specify this without having it mentioned as well in the root url file?

Comment: shark.views.target won't know 'shark'. Do i need to import that?